# Project's exe from the bin folder acting different from the one in the VS Debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm very VERY new at C# and I have a question. I want to make a riddle for my friends. Anyway, I made a Console APP that when open asks you if you want to play a game, if you type Yes you get a "Good, now chenk your desktop. You've got a gift." message ... if they answer No then the app closes. Atleast that's what I get in the debug mode in VS (Pressing F5 or Ctrl + F5) Anyway when I go to the project's folder and open the .exe from there something else happens. The first "page" shows and asks me if I want to play a game. Now whatever I do when I press enter the exe will close. Why? I mean in the debug in VS it's working just fine. Why would that exe act differently and how can I fix it?

Edit: I guess there's something wrong with the code because when I start it with debugging it gives the same problem but when I start it without debug (Ctrl + F5) it works fine.

Comment: Can you provide any code as an example?  Try adding an all-encompassing try/catch clause temporarily and have it output any errors and then wait for user input. That way, you can see any error thrown before the console closes.

Comment: The code's in there http://pastebin.com/Fzqn4gNz.

As I said, I'm very newbie and I just started learning yesterday so ... yeah ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible you haven't built the latest build. You can do so by heading to the Build Output option and changing it from Debug to Release.

[image: Change Output]

Afterwards, head to the build menu and select "Build Solution". You should now have the latest build in you bin/release folder (you can verify by checking the Modified date).

[image: Build Solution]

**Update**:

After taking at look at your code you were missing one vital line, "Console.ReadLine();". Without it, you application will execute your Console.WriteLine(); and immediatly exit. "Console.ReadLine();" will allow your program to allow the user to press enter before exiting. Here is the [updated code](http://pastebin.com/diff.php?i=fMRQyztX).

Comment: Thank you. But I allready did that like 3 times. Still the same result.

Comment: Just added (Kinda by mistake) that before seeing your post, thank you so much.